# How can I set the width of the div to occupy the whole space when the resolution changes?

Tags: css

I'm using WordPress and a template I bought in order to build the website I'm having the problem with. The template is built to be responsive and I'm facing some problems that I no matter what I've tried I wasn't able to find a way to fix them.

There are two boxes that when re-sizing the window don't occupy all the available width.

Here's the `php` code:

```
<div class="gb_ff social_share bold font_x_small boxed2">
                     <span class="meta_title_social">
                           <?php gb_e('Share') ?>
                     </span>
                    <?php get_template_part('inc/social-share') ?>
                </div>

            <div class="gift boxed3">
                 <span class="gift_image">
                        <img src="http://topgreekgyms.fitnessforum.gr/wp-content/uploads/2012/12/gift.png";?>
                 </span>

                 <span class="gift_title">
                        <a href="<?php gb_add_to_cart_url(); ?>" class=""><?php gb_e('Buy for friend') ?></a>
                  </span>
            </div>
```

and here's the CSS

```
.gb_ff, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5 {
font-family: Arial;
color: #666666;
text-transform: none;
}

.social_share {
    width: auto;
    float: left;
    padding: 9px 0 0 0;
    }


.boxed2 {
    width: 300px;
    height: 65px;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    margin-top: 15px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    background-image: url(http://topgreekgyms.fitnessforum.gr/wp-content/themes/blank-child-theme/img/gradient.png);
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    background-position: center bottom;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #CCC;
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
    box-shadow: 0 1px 1px #7D7D7D;
    }

.gift{
    font-size: 0.6em;
    font-family: Arial;
    float:left;
    }

.boxed3 {
    width: 297px;
    height:65px;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    margin-top: 15px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    background-image: url(http://topgreekgyms.fitnessforum.gr/wp-content/themes/blank-child-theme/img/gradient.png);
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    background-position: center bottom;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #CCC;
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
    box-shadow: 0 1px 1px #7D7D7D;
    }

.gift_image {
    float: left;
    margin: 16px 9px;
    }

.gift_title {
    color: #666;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-family: arial;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-left: 3px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    line-height: 66px;
    }
```

The boxes I'm referring to are the ones that appear under the countdown.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know how your css is organized, but these lines should do it (assuming it's [specific](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/) enough):

```
@media all and (max-width: 900px) { /* this media query rule is probably
                                       in the css already. no need to repeat it*/
   .boxed2,
   .boxed3 {
       width: 100%;
   }
}
```

​
If it's the first time you're seeing/hearing about media queries, then [this](http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/) might be useful: [CSS Media Queries & Using Available Space](http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/)

Comment: Thank you for the reply and the links Joplo! To be honest I have started educated myself about the whole 'responsive' idea just today.

I managed to get it work with a couple of modifications.

For '.boxed2':
1. Removed the 'width' value and added 'padding'.
2. Because of the padding I change the media query width to '86%' instead of '100%'.

I did the same for '.boxed3'

Everything looks good at the frontend. I hope it's a good solution code-wise.

Comment: No problem. Glad I could help. -- That might not be the best solution - that's because, if you shrink the window a little bit more, 86% becomes too much - it will go past the container's width. One solution is to make the padding a percentage value, just like the width. In your case, the padding (padding-right) would be 14% (100% - 86% = 14%).

Comment: If you really want to have the padding in pixels though, you can tell the browser to put the padding "inside" the width, with this css rule: `box-sizing: padding-box;` (there's also `border-box`, which also puts the border inside - I actually make this my default by applying it to all elements in the top of my stylesheet `* { box-sizing: border-box; }`

Comment: If you want to support older browsers then box-sizing won't work. In that case, you can strip the width and the positioning styles (floats, positioning, etc) from the box and apply them on a new wrapping div. Leave/put the padding on the box and you get the same thing as you would with box-sizing: border-box;

Comment: Here's a fiddle comparing the "pixel padding" solutions http://jsfiddle.net/3PtQ2/2/

Answer (score 1):

In your desired media queries CSS set the width of those elements to be width:100% when the resolution is at a certain size.

The media queries are already there - you simply have to add a css rule for these elments in there.

Answer (score 1):

CSS media queries are used to apply certain styles for desired screen/window resolutions.
for example all your media queries i your theme are found in style-media-queries.css file.

Add this to your css

```
@media (max-width: 900px) {
   #boxed2, #boxed3{
     width:auto;
     float:none;
   }


}
```

You can read more about media queries [here](http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/responsive-design-with-css3-media-queries)